# Units of the Boltzmann constant in $2$ dimensions

Tags: thermodynamics, units

I am answering a question in which volume is given as $m^2$ which I assume means that the question is considering a $2$ dimensional box for the volume. I am trying to calculate $N$ using the given variables however if I don't adjust the units of Boltzmann's constant from $J/k$ to $J/m.K$ then the units won't cancel appropriately. So I am tempted to just use units of $J/m.K$ for it however am I allowed to do this, is there any repercussions for this? is the constant the same value?

Comment: Volume cannot be in $\mathrm m^2$. The question might be wrong.

Comment: Well, I thought so too, but apparently it isn't, we also simulated a 2d box with gas particles in it which can only move in the x and y direction, it is related to that.

Comment: need k to calculate temperature of this system as well and it wont work without the units of k being j/m.K

Comment: Then you might have to assume a thickness equal to the diameter of the particles.

Comment: I could do that, the degrees of freedom would also still be 2 wouldn't it? since there can be no movement in the z direction, what do you think?

Comment: Yes, this seems the most plausible way to approach the problem.

Comment: Alright, well I'll think on it, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

- The question is incorrect.
- The question is correct and you'd have to assume that the thickness of the container will be equal to the diameter of the particles, in which case, you'll be able to preserve the 2 dimensional characteristic of the motion and at the same time, you will also not face anh problems regarding the units.